# Output with cout << endl

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, output

So, i have a program where i include static lib.

After that i write this:

```
cout << 1 << endl;
```

And i have this many errors like this:

```
    1>RL.lib(Connection.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:LBR' specification
1>Ggsg.lib(StrategyInfo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _m_mem_nchar_undup
1>Ggsg.lib(StrategyLegInfo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _m_mem_nchar_undup
1>Ggsg.lib(ProductRmsInfo.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _m_mem_nchar_undup referenced in function "int __cdecl RApiImp::dupProductRmsInfo(class RApi::ProductRmsInfo *,class RApi::ProductRmsInfo *,int *)" (?dupProductRmsInfo@RApiImp@@YAHPAVProductRmsInfo@RApi@@0PAH@Z)
1>Ggsg.lib(OrderReportElseRqCtx.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _m_mem_nchar_undup
1>Ggsg.lib(PnlInfo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _m_mem_nchar_undup
1>Ggsg.lib(SubSymCtx.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _m_mem_nchar_undup
1>Ggsg.lib(RebuildBookRqCtx.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _m_mem_nchar_undup
1>Ggsg.lib(SubRqCtx.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _m_mem_nchar_undup
1>Ggsg.lib(SubWatchCtx.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _m_mem_nchar_undup
1>Ggsg.lib(TradeRouteInfo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _m_mem_nchar_undup
1>Ggsg.lib(PreSubmitOrderRqCtx.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _m_mem_nchar_undup
1>Ggsg.lib(RothFillsRqCb.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _m_mem_nchar_undup
```

When i write this:

```
cout << 1;
```

Working well. Whats the matter?

Comment: The errors look unrelated to the "cause".

Comment: Wildly guessing: Was the static library compiled against the same runtime library as your project? (Did the the `/MT`, `/MD`, etc. option match up?)

Comment: The library could be redefining `endl` and it's doing something weird. Get rid of `using namespace std;` and prefix `cout` and `endl` with `std::`.

Comment: but if i remove "endl", this errors are disappear and i dont understand this..

Comment: @Carcigenicate i think about this, it doesnt works.

Comment: @Wintermute sry, more info: i have my lib "RL" and lib "Ggsg", both of them mdd. (RL includes Ggsg and then my app includes RL)

Comment: Does your project also use `/MDd`, like the libraries?

Comment: Alas, then my wild guess was wrong (it's always the first thing to check when I get nonsensical linker errors with MSVC). Hmm...is `m_mem_nchar_undup` a symbol defined in one of those libraries? I can't seem to find anything on it.

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if instead of `endl` you add `cout.flush()` at the end?

Comment: @ChristianHackl if i do this: `cout<<1;cout.flush();` working good. But it does not transfer to the next line. And `cout<<1 << flush;` working without problems.

Comment: @Wintermute no, 100% its not define in "RL.lib", but in "Ggsg.lib"(i dont have source files) only header and lib. In header - no.

Comment: Ask someone to walk you through it. SO is not a live help assistant and this is not a reproducible example.

Comment: @mrglut: So `cout << 1 << "\n" << flush;` will probably work fine. But it would shadow the real problem here. I've never seen a function called `_m_mem_nchar_undup`, and even Google has nothing about it.

Comment: @ChristianHackl yeah it is working! I will use this variant.. 
i only search `_m_mem_nchar_undup` in source file, i dont know what is it too.

Comment: @mrglut: While it's nice that it now works, I strongly recommend you continue looking for the reason it failed to link. Fixing something by sheer coincidence without understanding what's going on is never a good idea in software engineering. It has the potential of eventually biting you with further linker error, or worse, run-time errors.

Comment: @mrglut: btw, you should also search for `_m_mem_nchar_undup` in the source code of all libraries you use, provided you have the source code. Or at least have look in the compiled library files themselves.

Comment: @ChristianHackl ofcorse i will continue searching poblem...And this would be a temporary solution. Thank you for help!

Comment: @ChristianHackl i have some new info: if i use cout << endl in my lib (RL.lib) - working good. Only in main cant do this. RL - dont have defines and i think, maybe i need to change anything in propetise of my lib?

Comment: I found the problem. I have lib (Ggsg.lib), which refers to other libraries built into it. I used to think that it is necessary to refer only to the main library in linker settings. Include all libraries in linker settings solved my problem. Thx for help and sory for my fault..